# Redirect Rule in .htaccess php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to redirect this URL `http://www.example.com/blog/Title-here` to my `blog.php` page

Please note `Title-here` can be anything.

How I can do that ?

I am trying following but it's not working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/?$ blog.php [NC,L]
```

I don't know why.

Following is my full .htaccess code, may be here's the issue.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ product.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ results.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ results.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/?$ blog.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php
```

Comment: You want to redirect only to `blog.php`, without the title?

Comment: @brombeer The OP probably means a “rewrite”, not a “redirect”. The title can then be read from the requested URL (front-controller pattern).

Comment: Do you also have a directory named `blog` ?

Comment: @AmitVerma No, only blog.php file

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Since you are using very generic regex(not giving any uri condition in it) so its not reaching to your last rule of blog page. Keep it as your first rule like as follows. I have also fixed your regex in your all existing rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
###Making Rewriteengine ON here.
RewriteEngine ON

##Placing rule for URIs starting from blog here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog  blog.php [NC,L]

##Placing rule for url like: http://localhost:80/test1/test2/test3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*)/(?:.*)/?$ product.php [L]

##Placing rule for url like: http://localhost:80/test1/test2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(?:.*)/?$ results.php [L]

##Placing rule for url like: http://localhost:80/test1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ results.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick reply, still this ```http://www.example.com/blog/title``` redirect to 404.php, all others (results.php, product.php) working fine.

Comment: @AmanSharma, oh ok, where is your blog,php file present? Is it sitting besides htaccess file? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Both files are in root directory, same folder.

Comment: @AmanSharma, ok try changing rule to `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/?$  /blog.php [NC,L]` once? Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: No, it's same...redirecting to 404.php page.

Comment: @AmanSharma, this should actually work, could you please do let me know if you have any other htaccess file in your any of the directory?

Comment: No, only one .htaccess file.

Comment: @AmanSharma, ok 2 things here, 1st- Are you using same htaccess rule file(which I posted with changes to your rules also? Or you only added mine new rule?). 2nd- Please do let me know folder structure example(/root/.htaccess and /root/blog.php etc). Kindly do let me know these details.

Comment: Yes I am using same rules which you have written above. I am not adding any new rule. Folder for blog.php=> /var/www/html/blog.php & for .htaccess=> /var/www/html/.htaccess

Comment: @AmanSharma, ok sure, could you please change blog rule to following, `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(blog)/(.*)/?$ blog.php [NC,L]` they are new lines 1 condition and 1 rule please do implement it once and let me know then.

Comment: Need to replace all blog's rule three lines with these two lines ?

Comment: @AmanSharma, sorry for confusion, no place above mentioned 2 rules below these 2 rules `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` donut will be 3 conditions and 1 RewriteRule for blog. Let me know how it goes?

Comment: No, same result :( FYI now even http://www.example.com/blog redirecting to 404.php but according to our rules it should go to results.php isn't ?

Comment: @AmanSharma, oh ok, please try my edited rules in my post now and let me know  how it goes? I am trying my BEST to help you brother :) cheers.

Comment: Not working, http://www.example.com/blog redirect to http://www.example.com/404.php. It means only blog's rule is not working.

Comment: @AmanSharma, Hello Aman, did these worked for you? Or you got any workaround for these? Please do let me know(for learning purposes).